# does sg_set_page() supports zero bytes?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

```
<linux/scatterlist.h>
sg_set_page(sg, virt_to_page(buf), buflen, offset_in_page(buf));
```

The function sg_set_page() is working fine for non-zero buffer size but my linux driver crashes when it receives 0 bytes data so I'm wondering if this sg_set_page supports zero byte buffer?

Comment: By itself, `sg_set_page` just assign fields of the `scatterlist` structure. So. by itself it cannot crash. Probably, your **other code** incorrectly processes such structure.

Comment: Another possibility is that the hardware DMA controller might not support a zero-length transfer.